# Override $_POST content

Tags: php, post, sanitization

My question is that how can I directly override POST/GET or simply $_REQUEST values in PHP. Most of the scripts I've seen, simply assign a variable to the POST key, and do their desired stuff with it.

I simply need to **sanitize** the inputs, but my condition is that: I don't have to use the variable for it. For example:

```
$_POST['name'] = "Example's";
```

But, I need to override this POST value to:

```
$_POST['name'] = 'Example\'s';
```

But, without assigning the variable. In this process, I directly need to edit the value of the POST keys. I tried creating a loop and then doing my filtration process within it but that didn't help me.

Any idea, how to make this run? I'm sorry if I'm not being clear.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in your $_POST array. It also sounds like you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alright, found a fix.**

Realized that it's as simple as:

```
function cleanInput($input) {

  $search = array(
    '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',  
    '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',           
    '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',   
    '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'       
  );

    $output = preg_replace($search, '', $input);
    return $output;
}

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   $_POST[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,cleanInput($value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't access global variables directly, instead you should use filter functions like filter_input(): 
`$sanitized_var = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'var_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)`

Comment: But, I badly need to override the values directly by editing the global variable, instead of assign a local variable and then doing my operations with it.

Comment: Do you care to explain why do you need it?

Comment: Somehow, the POST values are deemed to be used directly in the script, so they must be sanitized before.

Comment: @Areeb There is no such thing as *sanitizing* your variables. It all depends on how you are going to use them, do you need to store them in a database, output them to html, etc.?

Comment: You can always assign a value to the $_POST array although I wouldn't advise it `$_POST['var_name'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'var_name')`

Comment: Well, to protect against SQL injections I'd probably need to escape the strings.

Comment: @Areeb or you could use parameter binding

Comment: Thank you; I'd wait for some time for more answers.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I forgot the third parameter of the function :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to escape every `$_POST` value like so:

```
$data= array_map(
  function($element) { return htmlspecialchars($element, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); },
  $_POST
);
```